# Creating successfully console window but cout doesn't print anything on it ( visual studio enterprise 2015 )

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I've created dynamic dll.
The interesting thing that the same code what I'll build in visual studio 2010
works just fine but while building the code on visual studio 2015, it doesn't work.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#define EXP __declspec(dllexport)  __stdcall
using namespace std;

void SPGoConsole(int status);
void EXP ttest(int in)
{
    SPGoConsole(1);
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
}

void SPGoConsole(int status)
{
    if (status == 0)
    {
        FreeConsole();
        return;
    }
    int hConHandle;
    long lStdHandle;
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO coninfo;
    FILE *fp;
    AllocConsole();
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &coninfo);
    coninfo.dwSize.Y = 1000;
    coninfo.dwSize.X = 1000;
    SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coninfo.dwSize);
    lStdHandle = (long)GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    hConHandle = _open_osfhandle(lStdHandle, _O_TEXT);
    fp = _fdopen(hConHandle, "w");
    *stdout = *fp;
    cout = fp;
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    lStdHandle = (long)GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    hConHandle = _open_osfhandle(lStdHandle, _O_TEXT);
    fp = _fdopen(hConHandle, "r");
    *stdin = *fp;
    setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    lStdHandle = (long)GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);
    hConHandle = _open_osfhandle(lStdHandle, _O_TEXT);
    fp = _fdopen(hConHandle, "w");
    *stde

    rr = *fp;
    setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    ios::sync_with_stdio();
}
```

I am not using any special settings in visual studio 2015.
Everything is default.

If I would use:

```
AllocConsole();
```

Then the first time my program imports the dll and calls ttest, It doesn't print out anything but second time It calls ttest it prints out Hello world!.

Then I tried just calling AllocConsole 2x but It still didn't print until 
my program called ttest again.

Edit: It appearst that after second dll import while program is running, it starts to print.

Anyideas?
Thanks